# show user account in php crud

Tags: php, crud

I'm building a php/sql crud.
sql query select: user = user id is not working...
What sql statement do i use to show only the users account info?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $user['id'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $user['username'];
    echo '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="detail.php?id=';
    echo $user['id'];
    echo '">';
    echo 'detail';
    echo '</a> ';
    echo '<a href="bewerk.php?id=';
    echo $user['id'];
    echo '">';
    echo 'bewerk';
    echo '</a> ';
    echo '<a href="delete.php?id=';
    echo $user['id'];
    echo '">';
    echo 'delete';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Show your sql query what you have wrote?

Comment: Show your tables or data models,  show queries, show what you have done.